# neo4j docker container shutdown on first query

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am trying operate a Neo4j database as docker container. I am using the official neo4j image. While I am able to startup and configure neo4j my container shuts down on the first query submitted via the web interface. I had no problems with the database and the query when operating the database outside of docker (Neo4j Community Edition).

I have already tried different configuration options regarding heap and page cache without success.

I am starting the docker containger using the following command:

```
docker run --detach --env NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size=2G --env NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=10G --env NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=20g --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --volume=c:/test/data:/data --volume=c:/test/logs:/logs --volume=c:/test/conf:/conf neo4j:latest
```

Unfortunately also the logfile of Neo4j does not give me any clues how to resolve this issue:

Debug Log: https://pastebin.com/nTLTFyqP

Comment: Is there anything in the `neo4j.log` file? Additionally, are you able to start up neo4j when you don't specify any NEO4J_* options at all?

Comment: Try running # docker run --detach --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687  neo4j:latest .... If it works then it means it is issue with other parameters

Comment: Seems like lack of runtime resources.. otherwise it works without any issue.

Comment: If I start the container without setting the environment variables the container does not shutown and the query executes correctly. However, in the default configuration I am running into timeout issues when executing multiple queries against the database after a few minutes. I am accessing the database via Spring Data Neo4j. Also the Neo4j manual states that the default configuration is just for learning and needs to be customized.

Comment: The mounted log directory only contains a debug log (as linked above). The log contains no runtime exceptions.